# RxJava: Observable that delays items until another observable has emitted?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I would like to delay an observable's emission until it receives a signal from another observable.

```
content: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
green:   ---G-----------
expect:  ---1234-5-6-7-8
```

This is my hacky solution:

```
    Observable.combineLatest(
      contentStream,
      greenLight, // Only emits 1 item when the time is right
      toPair(),
    )
        .map { it.first } // Prettify output as signal is not needed
```

Is there a more elegant solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concatArrayEager` with a `PublishSubject` as the first source so when you `onComplete` it, the operator will switch to the second source it has been running all along and relay past and future items.

```java
PublishSubject<ContentType> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<ContentType> source = ...

Observable.concatArrayEager(subject, source)
...

// later
subject.onComplete();
```